# Questions marked as duplicate has wrong title of original question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059036/how-to-get-string-list-of-enum-descriptions) question which is the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings) one. However, as shown in image, the original question title is different than the actual title. On investigating, I found that the title of original question was edited, but this edit didn't reflect on the title that appears in duplicate question.

Is it by-design? If yes, why?

**Duplicate Question**

[image: Image 1]

**Original Question**
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Not a bug. Years ago, the duplicate banner wasn't a separate banner (like current ones which enable dupe targets to be added/removed etc...) It was just inserted as editable text into the top of a post instead - so if anything changed - it wouldn't matter as it was just text in the post itself.

Comment: I've updated the dupe-closed question.

Comment: I wouldn't normally bother, but I've reopened and closed as a dupe so it behaves as people would expect these days...

Comment: Not sure about what @JonClements comment about having the banner as editable text years ago (I might have started using SO later) and am also not sure how you guys changed that title ...But since its fixed, its okay for me :)

Comment: For those curious if you look at Rev #2 of the post - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13059036/2 - you'll see that the Community user just use to prepend text to the top of the question when closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I wonder if Shog has the power to do this in a single bulk script: for every post that has the old-style notification at the top and is closed as a duplicate, reclose with the new-style notification. Sounds like something that could be done and shouldn't be very hard. But he might have more important things on his mind.